# Using devise_security_extension with a Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to use devise_security_extension with an existing Rails 3 application, so I can control the following:

- Insure that passwords are at between 8 and 70 chars long, and have at least one lower case character, one upper case character, one numeral and one special character.
- Old passwords are archived, up to 6
- Old passwords, not in archive, cannot be used
- passwords expire after 3 months
- Accounts that have not been used in more than 3 months are expired
- Sessions expire after 15 minutes of inactivity

I added the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise_security_extension', '0.10.0'
```

and to my config/initializers/devise.rb, I added the following:

```
config.expire_password_after = 3.months
config.password_regex= /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,70}$/
config.password_archiving_count = 6
config.deny_old_passwords = true
config.expire_after = 3.months
config.timeout_in = 15.minutes
config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = true
```

In my models/user.rb, I have the following:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invitable,
     :confirmable, :password_expirable, :secure_validatable, :password_archivable,
     :session_limitable, :expirable
```

I then did the following:

```
bundle install
rails generate devise_security_extension:install
```

But, I noticed that no migration files were produced. Am I missing any of the steps here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
rails generate devise_security_extension:install
```

does not create migrations, what it does is add optional configurations to `config/initializers/devise.rb`

For password_expirable and password_archivable you should create some migrations: a field to store date of password change...

```
rails g migration AddPasswordChangedAtToUser password_changed_at:datetime:index
```

... and a table to track old passwords

```
create_table :old_passwords do |t|
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false
  t.string :password_archivable_type, :null => false
  t.integer :password_archivable_id, :null => false
  t.datetime :created_at
end
add_index :old_passwords, [:password_archivable_type, :password_archivable_id], :name => :index_password_archivable
```

It's all explained at the github readme for the gem...

https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension